# Phantom NA records created by subsetting

Tags: r

Alright, I'm back and this time I've brought with me a reproducible example.

```
fileURL <- "https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Fss06hid.csv"
download.file(fileURL, destfile = "./acs.csv")
acs <- read.csv("./acs.csv")
mySubset <- acs[acs$ACR == 3 & acs$AGS == 6, ]
```

What I expect to see in `mySubset` is the 77 records out of the 6,496 that meet that condition.  However, what I end up with is my 77 expected records and 1,036 unexpected records which are completely `NA` for all the columns.

What am I not understanding here?

Comment: Try `mySubset <- acs[which(acs$ACR==3 & acs$AGS==6), ]`

Comment: That's a better solution.  I've been just !is.na() - ing on a random column but it was kind of driving me nuts that I wasn't following what was happening.

Answer (score 1):

Reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(NA, 1, 2 ,3), b = c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
df[c(NA, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), ]
#     a    b
#  NA NA <NA>
# 2   1    b
```

Basically,`NA` in the filter defaults the whole row to NAs.

To fix this behaviour your can use `is.na(df$a)` to check for missing values.